# Assumption violations with heteroscedastic data and OLS regression

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I'm trying to model the typical performance of an experimental approach I've developed. I have a total of 3000 observations for 72 different case studies. My observations consist of a reading for `size_x` and `size_y`, and the performance `n` for each point. `size_x` and `size_y` are both properties of each case study, and some case studies might have the same `size_x` or `size_y` values (or both).

[image: Response against size_x]

Performance is a function of the two measured variables, which are not necessarily independent (although `size_y` is always less than `size_x`, often much smaller). The relationship doesn't seem linear; it looks like it's some power of `size_x` and `size_y`. These are the only variables I want to model. To make things more difficult the two variables are correlated, although my question mostly relates to dealing with assumption violations of residuals:

[image: size_x and size_y]

I'd like to fit a model to the data I have to allow me to estimate the `n` for a given `size_x` and `size_y`. I have a problem that the data seem too heteroskedastic regardless of the transformation I apply. I've been able to get an $R^2$ of 0.914 and F-statistic of 4.6e05 if I apply a power transform to `n` using $\lambda = 0.3$ (obtained via Box-Cox), but the residuals from my model are not normally distributed (according to a QQ-plot of the scaled residuals).

[image: QQplot of residuals (scaled)]

A plot of the residual against the case shows the residuals have different centers for each case study, using either `size_x` or `size_y`.

[image: Residual vs size_x]

Given that linear regression assumes homoscedasticity and my residuals seem to violate the assumption that they are independent and normally distributed, what alternatives do I have? Am I right in thinking that the above $R^2$ isn't likely to be correct given the assumption violations I have? I'd appreciate any input or comments.

Comment: It looks like you have several observations at each level of the independent variables, in which case you could use weighted least squares to correct for the violation of heteroskedasticity.